# js code to make it work on all <div class="trend-content">

Tags: javascript

I have a js code that works, but the problem is that when I use it on the main HTML page, for some reason it only works on the first picture, although the LIKE icon is on all the pictures.

I do not understand why it is used only on the first value of the icon and not on the others.

How to make it work on all LIKE icons?

```
const likeIcon = document.getElementById('like-icon');
const likeCount = document.getElementById('like-count');


likeIcon.onclick = () => {
    const newId = likeIcon.getAttribute('data-news');
    const url = `/like_news/${parseInt(newId)}/`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'applicatin/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        if(data.liked) {
            likeIcon.classList.remove('empty-heart');
        }
        else {
            likeIcon.classList.add('empty-heart');
        }
        likeCount.innerHTML = data.like_count;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<section class="trend">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flex align-center justify-between trend-header">
        <h2 class="subtitle">
          <i class="ri-fire-line subtitle-icon"></i>
          В тренде
        </h2>
        <button class="btn btn-outline">Посмотреть все</button>
      </div>

      <div class="trend-content">
        {% for new in news|slice:"2" %}
        <div class="trend-card">
          <img src="{{new.banner.url}}" alt="newsPhoto" class="trend-background" />
          <div class="card-header">{{new.category.title}}</div>
          <div class="card-bottom">
            <h3 class="card-title">
              {{new.title}}
            </h3>
            <div class="card-btn">
              <div class="count" id="like-count">{{new.likes.count}}</div>
              {% if liked_by %}
              <button class="btn-up" class="fa fa-heart">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i id="like-icon" data-news="{{new.id}}" class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
              </button>
              {% else %}
              <button class="btn-up" class="fa fa-heart empty-heart">
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i id="like-icon" data-news="{{new.id}}" class="fa fa-heart empty-heart"></i></a></li>
            </button>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Tried to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll but couldn't do it

```
const likeIcon = document.querySelectorAll('#like-icon');
const likeCount = document.getElementById('like-count');
likeIcon.forEach(like-icon => {
    like-icon.addEventListener("click", () => { 
      const newId = likeIcon.getAttribute('data-news');
    const url = `/like_news/${parseInt(newId)}/`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'applicatin/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        if(data.liked) {
            likeIcon.classList.remove('empty-heart');
        }
        else {
            likeIcon.classList.add('empty-heart');
        }
        likeCount.innerHTML = data.like_count;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
          });
      }
}
```

And i expected it to work for all pictures that I had on main HTML page

Comment: 1. `like-icon` is not a valid variable name. Use underscore instead in the `forEach` callback fn. 2. `QuerySelectorAll` return a nodelist. Use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.like-icon')).forEach`

Comment: In your HTML, can you use a class for the 'like-icon' instead of an id and test it again? Id should be unique to only one element in html but seems like you have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Yea, I figured it out somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just needed to use querySelectorAll for like-count also, and also when using forEach method you need to pass index so every other likes will be separated

```
const likeIcons = document.querySelectorAll('#like-icon');
const likeCounts = document.querySelectorAll('#like-count');

likeIcons.forEach((likeIcon, index) => {
  likeIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newId = likeIcon.getAttribute('data-news');
    const url = `/like_news/${parseInt(newId)}/`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (data.liked) {
          likeIcons[index].classList.remove('empty-heart');
        } else {
          likeIcons[index].classList.add('empty-heart');
        }
        likeCounts[index].innerHTML = data.like_count;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class selector instead of ID selector.

While multiple Dom have the same ID, but only the first Dom can be query by document.querySelectorAll or document.querySelector.

Selects an element based on the value of its id attribute. There should be **only one element** with a given ID in a document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors

```
<i id="like-icon" data-news="{{new.id}}" class="fa fa-heart like-icon"></i>
```

```
const likeIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.like-icon');
// like-icon is not a right variable definition.
likeIcon.forEach(likeIcon => {
    likeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => { 
...
```

Comment: You may need to click the top arrow button of answers you like.